# Map Geolocation not working/ no display appearing

Tags: php, html, api, geolocation, maps

this is my first post and currently in a dire situation for a web development assignment, which requires us to create a php based website which allows the user to search for wifi locations with the use of google maps API. However when I run the code all i get is a blank map and no errors.

Help is much appreciated.

thanks

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!-- HTML5 doctype-->
    <html>
    <!-- Start of html document-->
    <head>
    <meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for Linux (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org"><!-- Header which calls the relevant stylesheets for display. It also outlines the page title and initial scale. -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta>
    <title>Reece &amp; Andy INB271 Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 480px), only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="small-device.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 700px), only screen and (max-device-width: 700px)" href="med-device.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 980px), only screen and (max-device-width: 980px)" href="large-device.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     <!-- source for the google maps api script-->
    function getLocation()
    {
            var x=document.getElementById("usercoords");

            if (navigator.geolocation)
            {
                    //runs showposition function
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
            }
            else
            {
                    x.innerHTML="Geolocation not supported.";
            }
    }

    function showPosition(position)
    {
            var x=document.getElementById("usercoords");
            //adds coordinates to html at id "usercoords"
            x.value=position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;
            document.getElementById("search").submit();
    }

    function initialize()
    {
            var mapOptions = 
            {
                    zoom: 10,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-27.4699404325,153.02562796)
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-search'), mapOptions);
            //sets markers
            setMarkers(map, hotspots);

    }
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
    </head>
    <!-- Body of the website containing the wrapper, nav, search and content divs. -->
    <body>
    <div id="wrap"><!-- The wrapper for the whole website -->
    <?php include 'header.php'; ?>
    <div id="content">
    <h1>Location Search</h1>
    <p id="Click">Click the button to get your position:</p>
    <button onclick="getLocation()">View Location</button> <!-- when clicked,  returns geo location marker on map -->
    <br>

    <div id="Breaker"><!-- Textbox field for the Hotspot name -->
    <p><label>Hotspot Name:</label> <input type="text" name="name"></p>
    <!-- Number input for the rating with a minimum of 1 and maximum of 5 (i.e. rating can't be 6 or 0) !-->
    <p><label>Hotspot Rating:</label> <input type="number" name="rating"></p>
    <!-- Radio button input that uses geolocation (if yes is selected and access is granted) to retrieve the user's current location !-->
    <p><label>Nearby Playgrounds:</label> <input id="r-yes" type="radio" name="geo" value="yes" onclick="getLocation()"><label for="r-yes" onclick="getLocation()">Yes</label> <input id="r-no" type="radio" name="geo" value="no" checked="true"><label for="r-no">No</label></p>
    <h4>Search By Suburb</h4>
    <!-- <!== search using the form-->
    <form id="form3"><!-- fields and styling for the dropdown -->
    <select name="Suburb">

    <option value="West End, 4101">West End</option>
    <option value="Wynnum, 4178">Wynnum</option>
    <option value="Zillmere, 4034">Zillmere</option>
    <!-- search box-->
    <!-- Onclick RETURNS RESULTS !-->
    <!-- closes the article --></select></form>
    <!-- closes the form --></div>
    </div>
    <!-- This is the page right sidebar and includes linkes to nearby hotspots and recent hot spot reviews. -->
    <?php include 'sidebar.php'; ?><!-- This is the footer for the website. It includes our student numbers, names and the council logo. -->
    <?php include 'footer.php'; ?></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: do you assign anything to hotspots?

Comment: i did, but for the sake of code length i've removed the code for hotspots which are simply map markers. (there were over 50 markers)

Comment: Where is the "map-search" div?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it contains to much information to diagnose the problem. Minimise your code to only isolate only the the code showing the problem ,http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, in doing so you may be able to identify and solve it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this google map's js.You're using this,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;sensor=false">
```

Instead of try with following,

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE&sensor=false">
</script>
```

Comment: no change, sorry
im getting no map whatsoever.
is there something wrong with my function initialize()?